# jQuery $.ajax DELETE not hitting then()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some code in a Chrome extension that's successfully using the `then()` from the xhr response of `$.ajax`.

```
  if (request && request.action === "updateTask") {
    $.ajax({
      type: "PUT",
      url: config.updateTaskApiUrl(storage.apiKey(), request.calendarEntryId),
      data: request.data,
      dataType: "json"
    }).then(function(data) {
      sendResponse(data);
    });
  }
```

however, I now deleting a record and did the same:

```
  if (request && request.action === "deleteTask") {
    $.ajax({
      type: "DELETE",
      url: config.updateTaskApiUrl(storage.apiKey(), request.calendarEntryId),
      dataType: "json"
    }).then(function(data) {
      debugger
      sendResponse(data);
    });
  }
```

The `debugger` line above never gets hit. I've tried `done()` and putting the `success: function() {}` as a key in the call too.

The response from the API is returning a 200.

[image]

Any idea why it never hits the `then()`?

Comment: Doesn't the jQuery Promise have a `.catch(err)` method you can use to find out what's going on? Or a second rejected argument passed into the then-handler `.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)`

Comment: I used the 2nd arg to get the error response and it was caught there. The payload shows `statusText: 200`, why would it end up in the error state?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't set the dataType property on a `DELETE`. jQuery may see it as an error if there is no json in the response?

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter, even with it removed. Oh well, thanks for the idea! I just rescued it based on status in the failure function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like because of the return status code, it's interpreted as a failure. I grabbed it and inspected the status in the failure function:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "DELETE",
  url: config.updateTaskApiUrl(storage.apiKey(), request.calendarEntryId),
  dataType: "json"
}).then(function(data) {
  sendResponse(data);
}, function(data){
  if (data.status == 200) {
    sendResponse(data);
  }
});
```